# Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline for application code and SQL database objects deployments together in sync

Tags: azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, azure-pipelines, cicd

I wonder how the organizations are dealing with this problem. Do we have tools to deploy the SQL artifacts with code? I have a big project which has three components to deploy together. Angular for UI, .Net core for API and SQL objects (tables and stored procedure etc.). When a developer completes the development of a new functionality then he commits Angular code, API code and SQL tables and stored procedures. Now the challenge is to deploy all these three parts together ( in sequence of course ) through Ci/CD. I do not see any way to do this. I have tried out to do it but did not find the solution. For code , CI/CD pipelines is there but it is not in sync with the SQL objects. Do we have any way to do this?

if this is possible then please guide or provide link of tutorial or video or any course on Udemy or any other platform where I can get the step-by-step know how.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm quite sure that depends a lot on what RDBMS you're using. Also, googling that database and CI/CD most likely gives you idea what's available.

Comment: is there any other forum where I can get the solution. ? This type of scenario is widely available and there must be some practices to achieve the CI/CD. Without the database objects there is no meaning of CI/CD. Code deployment must be in sync with the database objects deployment. After googling it, I have seen nowhere the example of this.

Comment: Again, what is the RDBMS? Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL? Something else?

Comment: I am talking about SQL server

Comment: There's definitely a lot of material in google, youtube etc. for SQL Server CI/CD with azure devops. Even Microsoft has a tool for that, and it's called SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) -- and there's plenty of tools available from other vendors.

Comment: That I know but the problem is, it is not in sync with the code deployment. All the material available are either about SQL deployment or code deployment. No example I have seen yet which talks about both in sync. No tool is there which provides the CI/CD for both in sync.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. If you have all needed things in the same commit / PR, they should be in sync. I don't see why there should be any one tool for doing more than one thing.

Comment: We do not  have all the things in the same commit. Separate tools are available and they work separately. for code, whenever we commit, CI/CD is there with git repo or other repository. for SQL server, we have to do it with SSDT and it is separate than the code. I want to know is there any method or tool where they come together.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your problem. I think you need to re-write the question, because it's not a tool issue -- a tool can't just magically solve this if it's caused by your process. And you need to explain what happens in your process that causes your changes not to be in sync.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your time and interest. I just wanted to know if there is any single tool exists for both. If not then How the industry experts are doing this activity.

Comment: I already explained that, and internet is full of info about it -- but for some reason you're saying they don't work for you. That is what you need to explain in your question -- what are you doing and why don't the tools work in your scenario. Things like "I have tried out to do it but did not find the solution" are pointless because you don't tell WHY you did not find the solution.